# How to properly align the buttons based on the text

Tags: html, css

I have job notifications that I was displaying on my home tab, like below.

[image]

but sometimes if the job title text is long, apply and view buttons are not displayed properly.

[image]

```
    My CSS(For job title):
    
    .job-container .container .job-tile .job-card .heading {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        max-width: inherit;

    For job description:
    
    .job-container .container .job-tile .job-card .job-description {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 22px;
        overflow-x: scroll

For apply and view button css:

    .job-container .container .job-tile .job-card .job-buttons {
        bottom: 2%;
        width: 96%;
        margin-left: 6%;
        position: absolute;
```

Please help me to fix the issue, thanks

Comment: Please add your markup and CSS into a snippet for a [example].

Comment: Never use `position: absolute` for normal layout.